# How to get row index that match my where clause?

Tags: c#, winforms, filter

I have such a code:

```
var result = list3.Where(Srodek => list4.Any(x => x == Srodek.Srodek.category1)).ToList();
```

and I would like to be able to get index of each row, that fulfills this clause. How can I do it? Is it possible? List3 is my main list.

Comment: List3 is my main list holding all information. I want to filter it, according to field category f my class. List4 holds user choice of category. For example Dog, Cat etc. Now filtering works fine, but I want to get indexes that are matched by this where clause. Can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` has a signature that accepts a predicate that takes both the item and its index as input parameters. You may use that to save the indexes before the list is filtered:

```
var result = list3
    .Select((srodek, index) => new {
       Index = index,
       Match = list4.Any(x => x == srodek.Srodek.category1)
    })
    .Where(x => x.Match)
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, it is working very good, but how can I now change color of each row with this index that I received from Select clause?

Comment: This just gives you a list of the indexes. But yes, you may do whatever you want with the list. To me, that sounds like something you would do at the list item itself, though, and in that case you wouldn't need the indexes?

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve the problem. Thank you for help!